# Show keyboard in full screen mode in Android

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

The problem is that showing keyboard (set focus to `EditText`) switches off full screen mode of Activity: all bars become visible again. Snippet below shows how I do set full screen mode for an Activity. Is it possible to show keyboard in full screen mode? Thanks.

```
View content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
int v = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

v = v | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;

content.setSystemUiVisibility(v);
```